# Video capturing in nougat?

Tags: android, video, video-capture, android-7.0-nougat

**I am Create Video capturing app in nougat supported but i am capturing video and that video is capture and save to default camera folder but that result code is -1. I am using following code.**

```
public void startRecordingVideo() {
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        File mediaFile = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");
        videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**I am putting My onActivityResult code here**

```
if (requestCode == VIDEO_CAPTURE) {
            //if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                int width = 0, DisplayWidth = 0;
                //int height = 0, DisplayHeight = 0;
                if (new File(Constants.APP_PATH + "/myvideo1.mp4").exists()) {
                    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                    retriever.setDataSource(Constants.APP_PATH + "/myvideo1.mp4");
                    Bitmap bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();
                    width = bmp.getHeight();

                    VideoPath = Constants.APP_PATH + "/myvideo1.mp4";
                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    MainActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    DisplayWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                    String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                    int VideoDuration = Integer.parseInt(time);
                    if (width >= DisplayWidth * 1.5 && VideoDuration <= Constants.VIDEO_UPPER_LIMIT) {
                        new ResizeVideoTask(VideoPath).execute();
                    } else if (VideoDuration > Constants.VIDEO_UPPER_LIMIT) {
                        showTimeDialog();
                    } else {
                        File afile = new File(VideoPath);
                        String path = Constants.APP_PATH + "/myvideo.mp4";
                        File destfile = new File(path);
                        if (destfile.exists()) {
                            destfile.delete();
                        }
                        copyFile(new FileInputStream(afile),new FileOutputStream(destfile));
                        Intent switchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,VideoActivity.class);
                        switchIntent.putExtra("URI", Uri.fromFile(destfile).toString());
                        switchIntent.putExtra("FILE_PATH", path);
                        startActivity(switchIntent);
                    }
                    retriever.release();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            } else {

            //}
        }
```

Comment: Your result is [`RESULT_OK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK). Why is this a problem?

Comment: I will remove it and try but videouri and path is not return to me and generate not found errors .

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit your question and show the code that **is** having the problem: your `onActivityResult()` method and how you are trying to use the `Uri` (not "path") that you are supposed to get back.

Comment: its right i am using MediaRecorder and save it but i am not get that uri so.If you known so tell me how to get it .

Answer (score 0):

First, you did not pass `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in the `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` `Intent`. As a result, the camera app will choose where to store the video, and it will return the `Uri` via the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`. You are not using that.

Second, if you uncomment your `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);` line (to fix the problem from the preceding paragraph), the `videoUri` that you are using here is defined differently than anything that you are using in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Thanks friends but already try it but result code is -1 and intent data = null return to me in nougat .

Comment: @Kuldeep: I do not know what "it" is. If you do not have `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and the camera app is not returning a `Uri` to you, then you are working with a buggy camera app. If you are now including `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you will not get a `Uri` returned to you in `onActivityResult()`, but you know where the video should be recorded.

Comment: Thanks friend but i am change my flow and create mannually camera and capturing video and its work fine and better for this . Why : I am not get any return uri and result so change this . Thanks you give me your important time .